# Reverse one logical bit in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, binary

Does it exist a better way to reverse an element of X?

```
>> X = dec2bin(10)
X = 1010
```

I did this:

```
x(i) = num2str(1-str2num(x(i)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to flip a bit of a numeric value `num` without converting it first to a character array of `'0'` and `'1'`, then you can use functions like [BITXOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitxor.html), [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html), and [BITSET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitset.html) (as [Andrey also mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809110/52738)):

```
num = bitxor(num, 4);  %# Flip the bit in the 4's place (i.e. bit 3)
%# Or ...
num = bitset(num, 3, ~bitget(num, 3));  %# Flip bit 3
```

However, if you *do* want to operate on the character array, you could also do this very strange thing:

```
X(i) = 'a' - X(i);
%# Or ...
X(i) = 97 - X(i);
```

This works because the [characters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-47856.html) `'a'` and `X(i)` are first converted to their equivalent Unicode UTF-16 numeric values before the mathematical operation is performed. Since the numeric value for `'a'` is 97, then a `'0'` (numeric value 48) or `'1'` (numeric value 49) subtracted from `'a'` will result in the numeric value for the other. The resulting numeric value on the right hand side of the equation is then converted back to a character when it is placed back in the character array `X`.

Comment: While this will work, IMHO it is not so good,  because you can't understand the meaning. So I won't downvote it, but still I think that you should consider code clearness.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand you correctly, and you want to set one bit to 1 use  **bitset**

```
bitset( x, bitNumber)
```

In case you want to flip a bit from 0 to 1 and vice verca, use **bitxor**

```
num = bin2dec('101110');  
bitNum = 1;  
res = bitxor(num, 2^(bitNum-1));
disp(dec2bin(res));
```

It is better, because you don't need to convert the number to **char** .