# Logical to char

Tags: matlab

I have a char array representing a binary number for example

```
bit <1x8 char> '00110001'
```

I want to replace the last char with a logical value. The following error is triggered: ***Conversion to char from logical is not possible.***

This is my code:

```
bit(end:end) = hiddenImg(i,j);
```

I checked that hiddenImg(i,j) is in fact a logical value.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808919/reverse-one-logical-bit-in-matlab/8809110#8809110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be optimal but should do what you want (convert the logical to a char):

```
>> bit = '10010100'

bit =

10010100

>> bit(end)=num2str(true)

bit =

10010101
```

Comment: That worked for me, however it seems that if conditional is more optimal. Thanks